# Stack Allocation Random Offset C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory, stack, memory-address

first of all this is on Windows 64 bit. As far as i understand, stack memory is allocated as soon as you enter a function. So in this case the interger should be allocated right at the beginning. Because of ASLR the location of the stack will be different across multiple runs, however i expected the offsets to the stack limits to stay constant. I wrote a function `GetThreadStackAddresses` that gets the upper and lower stack address of the current thread. However, what i noticed is that the offsets of the integer to the stack limits is pretty random aswell. Does Windows add a random offset to the stack pointer aswell? What else could be causing this? Thanks for any answers.

```
int main()
{
    int someInt = 123;

    Process::Stack stack{};
    if (!Process::GetThreadStackAddresses(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), stack))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "stackLimit: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << stack.Limit << std::endl;
    std::cout << "stackBase: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << stack.Base << std::endl;
    std::cout << "someInt: (0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << (uintptr_t)&someInt << ") = " << std::dec << someInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "someInt Offset to Limit: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << (uintptr_t)&someInt - stack.Limit << std::endl;
    std::cout << "someInt Offset to Base: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << stack.Base - (uintptr_t)&someInt << std::endl;
}
```

This is the output i am getting across different runs.

```
stackLimit: 0x1000FD000
stackBase: 0x100100000
someInt: (0x1000FFCCC) = 123
someInt Offset to Limit: 0x2CCC
someInt Offset to Base: 0x334

stackLimit: 0x5B3B11D000
stackBase: 0x5B3B120000
someInt: (0x5B3B11F88C) = 123
someInt Offset to Limit: 0x288C
someInt Offset to Base: 0x774

stackLimit: 0x52887FD000
stackBase: 0x5288800000
someInt: (0x52887FF9AC) = 123
someInt Offset to Limit: 0x29AC
someInt Offset to Base: 0x654
```

Comment: We can see that it does, obviously. What's your question exactly?

Comment: I dont think its ASLR doing this. I want to know why this is happening, i can see that it is happening myself.

Comment: ASLR is doing this. Disable it and you'll see all offsets become fixed.

Comment: yeah you are right i tested it, thanks

Comment: i somehow thought that ASLR would only randomize where the stack would be located, not the offset at which allocations inside the stack would be happening